# How do you make your datasource a string in Swift?

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm working with a UITableView and thus UITableViewDataSource. My dataSource is

```
        theTableView.dataSource = self
```

but I would like to have the UITableView get its data from a variable called 'phone' which is a String. Doing so currently errors to "String is not identical to UITableViewDataSource".

How do I get the UITableView to take its data from a string variable?

Thank you - hope this ends up being of use to others as well.

(For some background that's immaterial to others looking for the same solution: var 'phone' is a phone number being pulled from the user's contacts via the Contacts framework. I'm trying to get the UITableView to take in new phone numbers each time they're selected).

Comment: I guess you did not get the concept. `UITableViewDataSource` is a class which has several methods that are called from the table when it's time to display the single cells. You need to implement that.

Comment: All the required methods have been implemented and code is error free - I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to set the tableView's data source to a class that conforms to the UITableViewDataSource protocol. And then define the tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) function.

Example:

```
import Foundation

class Example : UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var dataSource = [ "hello", "how", "are", "you" ]

    // MARK: Lifecycle
    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // MARK: Data Source / Delegates
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataSource.count
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```